# How to use ES modules in Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

##### app.js

```
export const temp = "Hello World";
```

##### app.test.js

```
import { temp } from "./app.js";
```

When I run `npm test` it throws *"SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"*

This is the `test` script: `{scripts: {test: "jest"}}`

I've enabled ES modules by adding `"type": "module"` in `package.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the `experimental-vm-modules` flag

`package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you followed the instructions provided on [the ECMA Modules page](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) of the Jest documentation. If that doesn’t work, can you provide a reproduction? It would also help to know your version of Node/Jest/etc.